# what is a good word to describe a movie that left a strong feeling or impact in you?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

For example what is a better word to replace "struck" in the following example.

> I watched the Movie ABC today and what John said about gossip really
>   struck me.

Update: The word I was looking for was enthralled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canadian film "Incendies" had an **overwhelming impact** on me. When I left the theatre I could hardly walk."

Answer (score 1):

"Struck a chord with/in me" is clearer. You could also say "That was a very *moving* movie," although in that case you'd probably use "film", instead.

Also: *Eye-opening*.

Comment: If I say "struck a code" wouldn't that mean I'm reminiscing something? I want the impact to be something new and I will remember forever. Do you know if there is a word for such feeling?

Comment: Reminiscing perhaps,but "struck a chord" is more about the feeling or emotion that is stirred, than the specifics of a memory of similar emotion. "Eye-opening" means (more likely) a new experience.

Answer (score 1):

Disturbing if it had a negative psychological impact.  Memorable and gripping would describe for me a movie that takes hold of me for a while.

Answer (score 1):

For direct replacement: 'stuck with', 'affected'

If positive/negative: 'impressed' / 'disturbed' (see OSFox above), 'bothered', 'unsettled'

With slight rewording: 'consumed my thoughts', 'prompted a lot of thought about', 'fixed my thoughts', etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Made an impression** on me. **Moved** or **stirred** me also could work fine.